# Python: How to set BaseUrl in pdf metadata?

Tags: python, pdf, metadata, pypdf

I would like to add metadata to PDF in python.

I have used PyPDF2 and it works fine with metadata (tags) except of "BaseUrl"

**Code:**

```
dict_1['/BaseUrl'] = 'http://bud-arch.pollub.pl/wp-content/uploads/Bud-arch_171_2018_005-012_Boruci%C5%84ska%E2%80%93Bie%C5%84kowska_Maciejko.pdf'

writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

writer.addMetadata(dict_1)
```

The result is metadata "BaseUrl" in the section for creator free tags. not in section "advanced". How to solve this issue?

Łukasz

[image: screen from pdf properties, in Polish - sorry, to show what I mean]
<sub>(source: [pokazywarka.pl](https://static.pokazywarka.pl/r/b/k/3f0b38d41da6c88d4bda6fc7643ea3e0_big.jpg?1524303647))</sub>

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of a better quality. I can hardly see a thing.

Comment: [better quality] (https://imgur.com/a/Ys3yGCg)

Comment: better photo, i do not know how to use imagure.
This one is fine :
(http://pokazywarka.pl/i84sab/)